# How to read table data row by row of postgres db using shell script

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

How to read table data row by row of postgres db using shell script.

I tried out this:

```
psql -d db_name -t -c "SELECT * FROM table_name" | while read -a Record ; do
echo $Record[0]
echo $Record[1]
done
```

but this apporach is giving me data like:

```
Apple
|
```

Why this `|` is coming when I'm fetching row data only.

Actually I want to create json objects out of a db table data.
in the format:

```
column-name : value,
column-name : value
..... ;
```

Something like that

```
Table name -> student

Fields :
id : string
name : string
age : int
inSchool : boolean

Table data : 

ID   Name   Age  inSchool
1    Amit   18    Yes
2    Sunil  21    No
3    Anil   17    Yes
```

The output i want :

```
[
{
   id : 1,
   name : Amit,
   age : 18,
   inSchool : 1;
}, 
{
   id : 2,
   name : Sunil,
   age : 21,
   inSchool : 0;
}, 
{
   id : 3,
   name : Anil,
   age : 17,
   inSchool : 1;
}
]
```

If there's is any good way, please help me.

Comment: If you want json, then why not simply use `jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(table_name))` instead?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can u give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: `-t` turns off the column names.  It doesn't turn off the field separator.

Comment: Please provide table description (DDL) and sample data, as text **no images**.

Comment: @Belayer I have edited my question and included sample data as well. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Let Postgres do the aggregation and spool the output into file after turning off header formatting:

```
postgres=> \t
Tuples only is on.
postgres=> \o data.json
postgres=> select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s)) from student s;
```

Or in a single line:

```
psql -d db_name -t -c "select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s)) from student s" -o data.json
```

After that, the file data.json will contain the entire table as a huge JSON array.

Comment: what are s and t here select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(s)) from student t ?

Comment: @NitinSinghal: sorry, should have only be `s` - it's a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES)